# jQuery UI nested sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm working on a Script to easy sort nested lists with jQuery UI.
It works all fine, but there's one little "bug" that I couldn't erase.

Use jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fewTp/) and the instructions below to get see whats happening :)

The "bug" happens if you drag a sub-point one level deeper (drag "submenu2" a bit to the right and drop it, so it is a level deeper) and than try to drag it back again.
As you can see, in the moment that you drag "submenu2" a bit to the left, "submenu1" will jump down.

If you don't like jsfiddle here's my code for you:

HTML:

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        <span><p>menu 1</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 1</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 2</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><p>menu 2</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 1</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 2</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    font-family: Arial;
}
span {
    cursor: move;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
   /* margin-bottom: -62px;*/
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #793D00;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 180px;
}
.highlighter {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: move;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px 14px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    background:#FFFF91;
}
ul {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 6;*/
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
li ul {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
li ul.ui-sortable {
    min-height: 60px;
    /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 5;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
ul.no-child {
    margin-bottom: -73px;   
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    $('ul').disableSelection().sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    cursorAt: {
        left: 40,
        top: 20
    },
    cursor: "move",
    opacity: 0.5,
    placeholder: "highlighter",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: 200,
    start: function(e, ui) { 
        if(ui.item.parent().hasClass("children-1")){
            ui.item.parent("ul").removeClass("child").addClass("no-child");
        }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) { 
        mkUl();
    }
});

function mkUl(){ 
    $("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("class");

        var ulLevel = $(this).parents('ul').length+1;
        $(this).addClass("ui-sortable no-child level_"+ulLevel);
        var childC = $(this).children("li").size(); 
        $(this).has("li").removeClass("no-child").addClass("child children-"+childC);

        $(this).children("li:first").addClass("first");
        $(this).children("li:last").addClass("last");
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    mkUl();
});
```

Comment: This question is useful to so many people. It's absolutely mesmerizing to me why someone would characterize it as being "too localized".

Comment: Also interested - there are a few other similar questions on the topic too.

Comment: I have a parent div wrapping my ordered list element
If I put overflow:auto; on this div it stops jumping!